# How to target grandchild of post_parent using wp_list_pages

Tags: php, sub-menu, wp-list-pages

I have a much larger problem I posted earlier (still unanswered) which I might be able to solve if I can find a way to target the grandchild (or third level post) of a parent post.

Right now, this code:

```
$Pages = wp_list_pages('child_of='.($post->post_parent != false ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID).'&title_li=&echo=0')

echo $Pages;
```

Will show 2nd and 3rd level pages (bold=visible in submenu).

- Home
- Parent (active page)

  - **Child**

    - **Grandchild**

I need to find a way to preform a `str_replace`on the grandchild.

I know how to target the child, but basically need to do the exact same thing for the grandchildren.

```
$Pages = wp_list_pages('child_of='.($post->post_parent != false ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID).'&title_li=&echo=0')

$Pages = str_replace($Pages,
                     '<ul id="test">'.$Pages.'</ul>',
                     $Pages);
echo $Pages;
unset($Pages);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
$Pages      = wp_list_pages('child_of='.($post->post_parent != false ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID).'&title_li=&echo=0&depth=1');
            $InnerPages = wp_list_pages('child_of='.($post->post_child != false ? $post->post_child : $post->ID).'&title_li=&echo=0');
            $Title      = ($post->post_child != false) ? trim(get_the_title($post->post_child)) : trim(wp_title('', false));
            if($Title != '')
              $Pages      = str_replace($Title.'</a></li>',
                                        $Title.'</a>'.
                                        '<ul id="test"><li>Overview</li>'.$InnerPages.'</ul></li>',
                                        $Pages);
            echo $Pages;
            unset($Pages, $InnerPages);
```

**HOWEVER**, I have found a much better solution to accomplish what I was trying to do: [How to add active class to custom menu using while loop and wp_list_pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235468/how-to-add-active-class-to-custom-menu-using-while-loop-and-wp-list-pages)