# How to add active class to custom menu using while loop and wp_list_pages

Tags: php, functions, loop, menus, wp-list-pages

I am running `wp_list_pages` through a while loop to create a custom menu. By running it through a loop I can target specific elements to show. I need to figure out how to either target the classes autmotically created by `wp_list_pages` or to apply a custom active page class to the list my while loop generates.

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php echo '<ul>';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($query->have_posts()) {
      $query->the_post();

$child = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);

if( count( $child ) != 0 ) : ?>
      <li class="has-children"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
      <?php $children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0' );
      if ( $children) : ?>
           <ul class="children">
               <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Overview</a></li>
               <?php echo $children; ?>
           </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
      </li>                           
<?php else : ?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endif; 
}
echo '</ul>'; ?>
```

Which produces this output if on page 2.2 (notice the class `current_page_item`) :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://website.com/page-1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li class="has-children"><span>Page 2</span>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="http://website.com/page-2">Overview</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-115"><a href="http://website.com/page-2/page-2-1">Page 2.1</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-116 current_page_item"><a href="http://website.com/page-2/page-2-2">Page 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://website.com/page-3">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://website.com/page-4">Page 4</a></li>
```

If on page 1, the output is (notice no class indicating active page):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://website.com/page-1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li class="has-children"><span>Page 2</span>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="http://website.com/page-2">Overview</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-115"><a href="http://website.com/page-2/page-2-1">Page 2.1</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-116"><a href="http://website.com/page-2/page-2-2">Page 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://website.com/page-3">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://website.com/page-4">Page 4</a></li>
```

You'll notice that the li's in my second `<ul>` have the class `current_page_item` if on that page because I'm relying purely on `wp_list_pages` to generate the list. I want to find a way to add either an `active` class to the first `<ul>` if one of it's li's is the current page or target the classes that `wp_list_pages` dynamically creates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add class to the items in wp\_list\_pages](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113482/add-class-to-the-items-in-wp-list-pages)

Comment: Yep, that is why I linked to it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Add class to the items in wp_list_pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113482/add-class-to-the-items-in-wp-list-pages?rq=1)

Just add `<?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?>`. I added it to the `<li>` that contained my Overview link in the second level `<ul class="children">` as well as the `<li>` in the top level `<ul>` if the page doesn't have children.

```
<?php echo '<ul>';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($query->have_posts()) {
      $query->the_post();

$child = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);

if( count( $child ) != 0 ) : ?>
      <li class="has-children"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
      <?php $children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0' );
      if ( $children) : ?>
           <ul class="children">
               <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Overview</a></li>
               <?php echo $children; ?>
           </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
      </li>                           
<?php else : ?>
      <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endif; 
}
echo '</ul>'; ?>
```